# I m using jsp and servlet to uplaod 3 images, while storing in database the images have been interchanged

Tags: jsp, servlets

There is the html code.I want to fetch images by name of file.

```html
      <table>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td class="td-color">Upload Photo:</td>
      <td class="td-border">
      <input type="file" name="mphoto"/></td>
      <td class="td-color">Upload Applicant's signature:</td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="file" name="msignature"/></td>
      <td class="td-color">Upload Account Opening Form:</td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="file" name="accopenform"/></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
```

```
        Enumeration em = mpt.getFileNames();
        while (em.hasMoreElements()) {
            mptoken = (String) em.nextElement();
            fobj = mpt.getFile(mptoken);
            if (fobj != null) {
                mimg = fobj.getName();
                out.println("hi.." + mimg);
            }

            mptoken1 = (String) em.nextElement();
            fobj1 = mpt.getFile(mptoken1);
            if (fobj1 != null) {
                msign = fobj1.getName();

            }
            mptoken2 = (String) em.nextElement();
            fobj2 = mpt.getFile(mptoken2);
            if (fobj2 != null) {
                maocf = fobj2.getName();

            }
            mptoken3=(String)em.nextElement();
             fobj3=mpt.getFile(mptoken3);
             if(fobj3!=null)
             {
             mpkyfrm=fobj3.getName();  

        }
```

This is the servlet that I have been use, I want to get images from jsp by the name of img tago get particular image. How can i do it??

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the HTML code of the form you're using to send the files, and also describe more precisely what is the expected result, and what is the current result.

Comment: <tr>
                        <td class="td-color">Upload Photo:</td>
                        <td class="td-border"><input type="file" name="mphoto"/></td>
                        <td class="td-color">Upload Applicant's signature:</th>
                        <td class="td-border"><input type="file" name="msignature"/></td>
                         <td class="td-color">Upload Account Opening Form:</td>
                        <td class="td-border"><input type="file" name="accopenform"/></td>
                    </tr>

Comment: this is the html code....
 table has 3 columns named- Photograph varchar(60), Signature varchar(60), Openningform varchar(60).                                             
      When i m uploading these images, they stores in wrong columns i.e images interchanged

Comment: Edit the question, do not post code in comments.

Comment: It looks like... wrong implementation to uploading file in servlet throught jsp. Post complete code of servlet.